# Why Delphi Canvas.TextRect prints a String if I pass the value direct but not a String value coming from another class or database

Tags: canvas, vcl

Please help me to find out why the following codes doesn't work while the same code works if I pass the text as follows in Delphi 11.3

```pascal
//Working
var TextRect: TRect;
var myText : String;

myText := 'This is a test string';

TextRect.Top   := 0;
TextRect.Left  := 0;
TextRect.Height:= 80;
TextRect.Width := 200;

Canvas.TextRect(TextRect, myText,[tfCenter, tfWordBreak]);
```

```pascal
//Not Working
var TextRect: TRect;
var myText : String;

Text := myItemDescription.Text;
// or even if I pass a string from a database it doesn't work

TextRect.Top   := 0;
TextRect.Left  := 0;
TextRect.Height:= 80;
TextRect.Width := 200;

myPage.Canvas.TextRect(TextRect, myText,[tfCenter, tfWordBreak]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You assign to `Text`:

```
Text := 'This is a test string';
```

then you print `myText` instead:

```
Canvas.TextRect(TextRect, myText,[tfCenter, tfWordBreak]);
```

Isn't `myText` empty?

Also, an easy way to print text is:

```pascal
Canvas.Pen.Color := clblack;
Canvas.Font.Name := 'Arial';
Canvas.Font.Size := 8;
Canvas.TextOut(0, 0, 'this is my text');
```

Comment: It should be myText as it my spelling mistake .. I did try Canvas.TextOut but It doesnt provide the [tfCenter, tfWordBreak] options as if myText is very long automaticly it generates the multiline with WordBreak as I can do all with lots of calculations and code which is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make it work but it looks like it is a bug needs to be reported.

if I pass my string into myText string then it works .

```
myText := String(ItemDescription.Text);
```

Comment: `TextRect()` takes in a `string` variable by reference. It doesn't care where the value of that `string` comes from. I don't think the bug is in the VCL itself, it is more likely a bug in your own code instead. But what you originally posted is hardly a [mcve] to demonstrate the problem in action.